# Translation of "Thank you for your attention"

Tags: translation, word-choice

I'm looking for an equivalent of "Thank you for your attention", to be said/shown at the end of a conference presentation.

Is 感谢您的关注 adequate in this situation?

Comment: alternative:感谢您的注意,bkrs:  关注 [concern] 关心重视
我们密切关注事态的发展
我国政府对这一地区事态的发展表示严重关注,关心注意。
如：「多关注亲人的健康。」
或作「关垂」。多蒙关注。 Thank you for so much concern.
希望你对此给予关注。 I hope you will give attention to this problem.

Comment: Wonder ing why you need say ' thank you for your attention' at the end of a conference presentation?

Comment: I echo the above comment: For a conference presentation, why not simply conclude with "谢谢大家"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was also asked on [italki](https://www.italki.com/question/106548) in 2011. A native speaker of Chinese (from Taiwan) pointed out that (with my editorial corrections and added emphasis):

> At the end of a presentation, we say "Thank you for your attention!" for the end. But in Chinese we say, "**Thanks for your time**" / "**感謝諸位的時間**". The Chinese are a polite people. (It means that that we did NOT point out that you paid attention to my speech, so we only say, "Thank you for for your time". FYR)

The suggested expression in simplified Chinese characters is then **感谢诸位的时间** (gǎnxiè zhūweìde shíjian̄).

Answer (score 2):

"关注" and "注意" do means attention, but 感谢各位(的)聆听 will do better.

"聆听" has the meaning of "listening to" (paying attention to) to music or lectures.

It's just different expressions between languages.

Comment: I don't suggest 聆听. It sounds awkward if you use it in a live presentation. The word 聆听 is usually used on radio programs.

Comment: Especially if a man says it. It sounds a bit girly.

Comment: Well, if you put it that way, I suggest just saying 感谢各位 / 谢谢各位 / 谢谢大家. Saying 感谢各位的关注 will work, but everyone can tell it's a literal translation from English.

Comment: Actually I do think "Thank you everybody" is the most common used term as "Thanks for your attention" in Chinese world.

Answer (score 1):

`谢谢您的关注\感谢您的关注` is adequate,

however if there are many people attending the conference, you can also say

`谢谢 大家\各位\你们\ 的关注`.

I'm too confused why you have to say this at the end of a presentation

Answer (score 0):

打扰您了！

dǎ rǎo nín le

Just in oral.

Comment: I won't use this "at the end of a conference presentation", which is what the OP asked.

Comment: @fefe  It’s up to the level of conference and the institution of the company you in. Making a short report or a simple conference presentation without much red tape. And it’s okay to say that.

Comment: I think you can include that in your answer.